# Change order of animation calls

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein

I have the following jquery to make all objects but the one hovered fade out and then fade back. However I want the element being hovered to fade to full opacity immediately, instead of waiting for the others to fade back.

```
$('a').bind('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(0,1);
        $('a').not($(this)).fadeTo('fast', 0.25);
    }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
        $('a').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/jQmZ3/1/

Comment: Did [`$(this).show()`](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/jQmZ3/2/) not work? (Also, your fiddle code doesn't match your question code.)

Comment: ah does show pop back to opacity 1? didn't realize it would have that effect. easier that fading to 1

Comment: I had a feeling that was all you were after. Check @BenEvans' answer just to check; if not, I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/jQmZ3/3/ ... Use a stop on all 'a' element's effect queues.

```
$('a').bind('mouseenter',function(){
    $('a').stop();                
    $(this).fadeTo(0,1);
    $('a').not($(this)).fadeTo('fast', 0.25);
}).bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $('a').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);  
});​
```

Comment: This just short-circuits the fade out/fade in. Not saying it's not an improvement, but it doesn't necessarily follow the prescribed behavior in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're needing is to "auto-focus" the hovered element, use `$.show()` to bring the element directly to the foreground. This works mainly because you cannot `fade in` this amount any more, thus you have the effect you desire.

```
$('a').bind('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).show();
    $('a').not($(this)).fadeTo('fast', 0.25);
}).bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $('a').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/jQmZ3/2/